# How to ensure asynchronous method has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am using the asynchronous/promise method using JavaScript

The following is a snippet of my code:

```
var func = new instance.web.Model("session.table").get_func("check_session_state");

func(session_id).then(function(res) {
    localStorage.setItem('session_state', res);
});

if (localStorage.getItem('session_state') == inactive)
    alert("Session Inactive !");
```

The problem is that the 'if' condition gets invoked before the session_state variable is set, and throws an erro. How do I ensure that the result is available before continuing execution?

Comment: include your session_state dependent code in your callback

Comment: refer to  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. $.ajax

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that it is also set `.then()` your if code as well:

var func = new instance.web.Model("session.table").get_func("check_session_state");

```
func(session_id)
.then(function(res) {
    localStorage.setItem('session_state', res);
})
.then(function(){
  if (localStorage.getItem('session_state') == inactive) {
    alert("Session Inactive !");
  }
});
```

I would also recommend [jshinting](http://www.jshint.com) your code.

Answer (score 0):

You move the if condition into the callback function.

```
func(session_id).then(function(res) {
    localStorage.setItem('session_state', res);
    if (localStorage.getItem('session_state') == inactive)
        alert("Session Inactive !");
});
```